# How make a message box popup if there is space in text entered in a textbox

Tags: vb.net

I have a textbox where a name is entered and the name should not contain any spaces, so if text with spaces is entered i want a message box to popup...

Comment: Split your problem into smaller simpler one. Can you extract the text from a textbox? Can you check if there's a space? Can you show a message box? Do you know which event you want this to happen on?

Answer (score 1):

This code displays a messagebox if the value of a textbox(named textbox) contains a space.

```
dim mystring as string = textbox.text

if mystring.contains(" ") then
     messagebox.show("This text contains a space.")
end if
```

Comment: You may want to add some comments about what your answer does/is.

Comment: @Whymarrh What line of the code does he need to explain actually